# My angular function is not being executed on the first call. It is only being executed on the second call

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

The title is really not clear I grant you.
I have a variable in a component and I would like to use it in another component.
I created a service and observable in order to be able to transmit my data.
I send my data to my service then I head to the page that will retrieve this data.

```
        this.service.myMethod(this.ville);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/resto-by-ville');
```

Behind I get my data and use it like this:

```
getDataByVille() {
    this.service.myMethod$.subscribe((city) => {
        this.city = city;
        this.http.get<Etablissement[]>('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/etablissements/' + this.city).subscribe((data) => {
            this.dataByVille = data;
            console.log(this.dataByVille);
        });
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataByVille();
}
```

My service :

```
export class GetDataByVilleService {
    myMethod$: Observable<string>;
    private myMethodSubject = new Subject<string>();

    constructor() {
        this.myMethod$ = this.myMethodSubject.asObservable();
    }

    myMethod(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.myMethodSubject.next(data);
    }
```

My problem is that when I send a data absolutely nothing happens. If I repeat it a second time it will work.
I don't understand why it doesn't work the first time.
Do you have an idea? Currently it's not very UX friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a Subject does not store the value, so by the time you reach the 'tabs/resto-by-ville' page, the emit has already happened.

Instead of a Subject, you should use a BehaviorSubject, like:

`private myMethodSubject = new BehaviorSubject <string>(null);`

The BehaviorSubject stores the last value you gave it, and emits it as soon as you subscribe to it.

Comment: Or you might want to have a look at the [Angular Route Resolver](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/)

Comment: Love you dude !

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the observable pattern all wrong. They should be chained like this:

Service:

```
export class GetDataByVilleService {
  getDataByVille(): Observable<Etablissement[]> {
    return this.http.get<Etablissement[]>('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/etablissements/' + this.city)
  });
}
```

Component:

```
// Component under "tabs/resto-by-ville"
export class RestoByVilleComponent {
  dataByVille: Etablissement[];

  constructor(getDataByVilleService: GetDataByVilleService )
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataByVilleService.getDataByVille().subscribe(dataByVille => {
      this.dataByVille = dataByVille;
    });
  }
}
```

There is no need to call the service from the component you want to navigate from.